# Java Object returning class - Return String fails

Tags: java, string, dictionary, key

Error: the return type is incompatible with Map.Entry.getKey();

```
public class MEntry implements Map.Entry<String, Integer> {

@Override
public Object getKey() {
    Object o = this.getKey();
    return o;
}
```

Comment: Look at the return type of the method you're overriding...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You key is of type String as defined by `Map.Entry<String, Integer>` then you should return String as below:

```
@Override
public String getKey() {
    String o = this.getKey();
    return o;
}
```